# Two isomorphic subgroup of $\pi_1$ acts on the universal cover, can the quotient be homemorphic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $\widetilde{X}$ be the universal cover of a topological space $X$ where let us assume $X$ has $CW$ structute, then we know $\widetilde{X}$ has free $\pi_1(X)$ action. Let $A$ and $B$ be isomorphic subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$. Then the question is will $\widetilde{X}/A$ $\cong$ $\widetilde{X}/B$? it seems to me that it should happen. Or does it happen in a special case where $\widetilde{X}$ is contractible or something..

Comment: Do you know the classification theory of covering spaces? Also, $\tilde{X}$ is always contractible.

Comment: $\widetilde{X}$ is *not* always contractible. Take, for instance $X = S^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take $\cong$ in the question to mean "homeomorphic," the answer is no; if we take $\cong$ to mean "homotopy equivalent" and $\widetilde{X}$ to be contractible, the answer is yes.

Let $X$ be the rose with two petals, with fundamental group isomorphic to the free group on two generators $F_2$. Taking $A = \pi_1(X)$, and $B$ an infinite-index isomorphic copy of $F_2$ inside $\pi_1(X)$, we see that $\widetilde{X}/A$ is the rose with two petals and $\widetilde{X}/B$ is not even compact.

For the second remark, see for instance Hatcher Algebraic Topology 1.B.8-1.B.9. The point of the proof is that you try to construct a map that realizes the homotopy equivalence you want to exist by induction on the $n$-skeleton, and look at what can stop this from working. The obstruction would live in a non-contractible map from an $n$-sphere, $n > 1$, to $\widetilde{X}/A$ or $\widetilde{X}/B$. These cannot exist as a consequence of the lifting lemma and contractibility of $\widetilde{X}$.